# Why can't I find `"az"` in a string with this function?

Tags: ruby

I want to know if `"a"` and `"z"` are together in a string after I have found `"a"`. I'd like to understand why this does not work:

```
def nearby_az(string)
  i = 0
  while i < string.length 
    if string[i] == "a" && string[i+1] == "z"
      return true
    else
      return false
    end 
    i += 1
  end 
end
```

I realize there is a simple way to implement this. I am not looking for another solution.

Comment: What's the input in which you can't find "az"?

Comment: try "jimmaz" or "baz" or "jimmazuja"

Comment: You need to be more specific than "this is not working". Does it return `false` when you expect `true`, or vice-versa, and if so what is the value of `string` when that happens? I don't believe your code should raise an exception, but if that were the problem you would need to state precisely what the exception was and on what line it occurred. Your code is very un-Ruby-like (which you know), so after you get it working I suggest you post it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby) to obtain suggestions for improving it.

Comment: I knew that before posting the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will only find "az" if it's at the very beginning. Otherwise it will `return false`. Postpone `return false` until you walked the whole string.

```
def nearby_az(string)

  i = 0
  while i < string.length -1  
    return true if string[i] == "a" && string[i+1] == "z"

    i += 1
  end 
  # we can only reach this line if the loop above does not return.
  # if it doesn't, then the substring we seek is not in the input.
  return false 
end

nearby_az('baz') # => true
```

Comment: ahh I see. Thanks I will accept the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Just as a note, you don't actually need the `return` in `return false`.

Comment: @JustinWood: yeah, I just moved the original code around, to maintain similarity. Also, helps for clarity.

Comment: jgozal, Sergio answered your question, but if future consider waiting awhile (at least a couple of hours, say) before selecting an answer, and refrain from announcing that you will be selecting a particular answer. You don't want to discourage other answers and you should be mindful that others may be diligently preparing answers and could be a bit annoyed if you don't give them time to finish before making a selection.  Those giving answers do not expect a quick selection, but, mainly, there's no rush!

Answer (score 4):

[@Segio Tulentsev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32027607/633183)' s answer explains why yours is broken.

Here's the short implementation if you're interested

```
def nearby_az(str)
  !! str =~ /a(?=z)/i
end
```

Comment: yep you could also just do return true if string.include? "az". I couldn't implement that for my situation unfortunately.

Comment: I think I see another cavity, this one in your upper left premolar.

Comment: Note if you're looking for az together technically za satisfies this requirement. so you'd need (a(?=z)|z(?=a)) too. also if insensitivity is a requirement you'll need to add that.